# mercurialで特定のチェンジセットだけをブランチにコミットする方法

Tags: mercurial

masterとそのブランチがあるmercurialのリポジトリで、masterにある特定のチェンジセットだけをブランチにコミットしたい場合、もっとも簡単な方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 3):

[graft](http://mercurial-users.jp/manual/hg.1.html#graft)コマンドを利用します。

> ## [graft](http://mercurial-users.jp/manual/hg.1.html#graft)
>
> **別ブランチ上から現行ブランチへの指定リビジョンの複製:**
>
> *hg graft [OPTION]... [-r] REV...*
>
> 本コマンドは、 あるブランチから別のブランチへ、 Mercurialのマージ機能でリビジョンを複製しますが、 履歴上はマージされません。 これは 'backport' または 'cherry-picking' と呼ばれる機能です。 特に指定の無い場合、 ユーザ名、 日付、 コミットログは、 元リビジョンのものを再利用します。
>
> (中略)
>
> コミットログを改変しつつ単一リビジョンを stable へ複製:
>
> ```
> hg update stable
> hg graft --edit 9393
> ```